# Http client doesn't send a response or send a null - Angular and C# Api

Tags: c#, angular, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I stumbled upon a problem. I got an Angular 5 website and a backend based on C# WebApi.

In my webiste i got a component that is suppouse to send a post request to backend adding new entity to DataBase. Unfortunatelly it doesn't send a request or it isn's recieved on backend.

**bet.component.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Service} from './service';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import {AppConfig} from '../app-config';
import {Bet} from '../models/bet';

@Injectable()
export class BetService extends Service {

  private url = this.config.apiUrl + '/bet';

  constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig) {
    super();
  }

  addBet(bet: Bet) {
    return this.http.post(this.url + '/add', bet);
  }
}
```

**BetController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FakeBet.API.DTO;
using FakeBet.API.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FakeBet.API.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class BetController : Controller
    {
        private IBetService service;

        public BetController(IBetService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }

        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Add([FromBody] BetDTO bet) 
        {
            try
            {
                await service.AddBetAsync(bet);
                return Ok();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Url is ok.

I tried to change bet.component.ts to

```
return this.http.post(this.url + '/add', bet).subscribe(x => console.log('test'));
```

and then the response is recieved on the backend side, but `BetDto bet` is null.
While `bet` is not null and the names of the properties are the same in the object in Angular and Api.

I also tried to send a request using a Postman and it went smooth. Here's how it looks. [image: request]

Can someone tell me where's my mistake? Cheers!

**BetDTO**

```
using System;
using FakeBet.API.Models;

namespace FakeBet.API.DTO
{
    public class BetDTO
    {
        public Guid BetId { get; set; }

        public string MatchId { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public int BetOnTeamA { get; set; }

        public int BetOnTeamB { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**bet.ts**

```
export class Bet {
  matchId: string;
  userId: string;
  betOnTeamA: number;
  betOnTeamB: number;
}
```

- Request using website: [website request](http://pastebin.com/cLgFZHX4)
- Request using Postman:[postman request](http://%20pastebin.com/4QFbYWLW)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] not random parts of code

Comment: I don't see any `HttpClient` here. There's an Angular script that calls a Web API controller passing a JSON string in the body. If that body doesn't match the BetDTO class the parameter will be null. What does `BetDTO` look like? And btw the action method is named `Add` so the URL should be `/add`, not `addBet`

Comment: If POSTMAN worked, it means that the Angular and C# objects are *not* the same or that the requests were different. Use Fiddler to check how the two requests look and how they differ. Is there a missing content type header perhaps? Wrong encoding of the DTO?

Comment: is the content-type header being set in the angular part?

Comment: @LewisTaylor the headers aren't problem. It is set by default, i tried to set them manually and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i cannot run Fiddler on my system. I tried using chrome console and it looks fine when i'm using a request with a `.subscribe` method. POST request does containt my object in a body. Yet it ends up as null in my Api.

Comment: The question is *how does this differ from the POSTMAN request*. Post both requests here instead of an image of part of POSTMAN's request. `looks fine` doesn't mean anything when one request works but the other doesn't. What's the difference?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Request from website: https://pastebin.com/cLgFZHX4
Request from Postman: https://pastebin.com/4QFbYWLW

Comment: Post the requests *in the question itself*. Nobody will see this link in the comments. And remember to post *both* requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found a solution, and its something I would never expect to be a thing. 
So when i was requesting a resource on webapi i was passing a request with a one field equals to `"betOnTeamA" = ""` or something like this. But apparently when a field is like this then .net think than whole body of a response is null. So a solution is to simply change `"betOnTeamA" = ""` to `"betOnTeamA" = "0"`, and then it's working like a charm.

Comment: Are you talking about `BetOnTeamA `? If so, that makes sense, you can't convert `""` to an `int`.

Comment: @DanDumitru yea i meant it fixed.